# What is the number of non-negative integers with at most four digits at least one of which is equal to 7?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of non-negative integers with at most four digits at least one of which is equal to 7?

Comment: Use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: 3000 is the answer.

Comment: It is better that you post first your attempt, and then will be clarified possible troubles.

Answer (score 2):

So we allow the leading zeroes to pad the number to exactly $4$ digits and there will be $9^4$ such numbers without any $7$ out of total $10^4$ $4$-digit numbers, thus the answer is $10^4-9^4=3439$.

Python direct counting verification [here](https://tio.run/##FcgxDoAgDEDR3VN0o5CYQDRRBw7DANpBIAUTPD3iH97w81uvFJc9c@/NludGAyExEFAEdvH0aPRIAgUQm/h3qYwk5ZSZYsUmJ1eK5wrNWqOVWudj0PsH).

Answer (score 1):

We have four sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, consisting of the nonnegative integers less than $10,000$ that respectively have the first, second, third, and fourth digits equal to $7$.

First, add up the cardinalities of all four sets. This gives $|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|=1000+1000+1000+1000=4000$.

Then, subtract the cardinalities of all the binary intersections. This gives $4000-|A \cap B|-|A \cap C|-|A \cap D|-|B \cap C|-|B \cap D|-|C \cap D|=4000-100-100-100-100-100-100=3400$.

Next, add the cardinalities of all the ternary intersections. This gives $3400+|A \cap B \cap C|+|A \cap B \cap D|+|A \cap C \cap D|+|B \cap C \cap D|=3400+10+10+10+10=3440$.

Finally, subtract the cardinality of the intersection of all four sets. This gives $3440-|A \cap B \cap C \cap D|=3440-1=3439$.

The answer is therefore $3439$, using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.